Using PDFBox to convert PDF to JPG/PNG but missing a content
I'm using PDFBox version 3.0.2 (also tried on oldest version) to convert a file PDF containing e-signature to image JPG/PNG but missing a content
Here is
my PDF file
And converted image file
try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File("test-signed.pdf"))) {
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImage(0, 300 / 72f, ImageType.RGB, RenderDestination.PRINT);

    File file = new File("output.png");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
}

I need render all contents in pdf to image JPG/PNG
Why object William in pdf cannot be rendered but others can? Anyone can help?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Provide the source pdf Exactly

I bet that RenderDestination.PRINT is the key. Some annotations don't have the print flag.

Here is my pdf https://drive.google.com/file/d/167btZVobeGAV_SVRMsLnzLGxDCG05DPY/view?usp=sharing

This isn't the file... this one doesn't have the yellow, and has only "William" but not "sdf". And it hasn't been "signed". I looked at the file with PDFDebugger, the only image is "William", and "sdf" doesn't exist as an image resource or inline.

I looked at the new file, that one does have a JPXDecode image at Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Resources/XObject/Fm0/Resources/XObject/Im0/Filter so the missing library was may really have been the cause. (There is an error message about this too, unless logging was disabled)

I found issue.
That object is an image so need an image operator to render it.
I added 2 below libraries and it worked
implementation "com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-core:1.4.0"
implementation "com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-jpeg2000:1.4.0"

Thanks all

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
